# Error code C4 when installing Windows Server 2012 on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, windows-server-2012

I am getting error code [C4](http://media.askvg.com/articles/images5/Windows_8_1_VirtualBox_Install_Error.png) when trying to install Windows Server 2012 on VirtualBox. I was able to install this a few weeks ago. However I had to install a fresh copy again. This time however I always get error [C4](http://media.askvg.com/articles/images5/Windows_8_1_VirtualBox_Install_Error.png) no matter what I try.

Settings I'm using:

- 1024 MB base memory
- 2 Processors
- 27Mb video memory
- I have checked to ensure Intel Virtualization Technology (vt-x) is
  enabled in my BIOS.
- Also I have SetExtraData as suggested in [this post](https://4sysops.com/forums/topic/windows-server-2012-r2-on-virtual-box-error-0x000000c4/).

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try here: [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had disabled "Execute Disabled Bit" in my BIOS in order to install Windows Server 2008 R2 on my VirtualBox.

Re-enabling it seems to have fixed the issue with Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

fix C5 Error install Win2012 too (Disable Execute bit)